# Plotting Levenshtein distance scores in R

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to plot the Levenshtein distance scores between 2 list of sequences (amino acid sequences) using something other than a heatmap. This is a code I used to generate a heatmap as an example:

```
library (utils)
library (pheatmap)
dist_scores<-adist(LV #first list of sequence
,CD4 #second list of sequences, counts = TRUE)
colors = c("tomato","khaki1","darkseagreen2", "mediumseagreen", "gray30")
breaks <- c(0, 1,2,3,4,5)
pheatmap(dist_scores,breaks=breaks, color=colors,  cluster_rows = T, cluster_cols = T)
```

and here is the heatmap from the example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ay55.png

I want to have a more intuitive way of showing the data..
I'm thinking of plotting the data as nodes (representing different sequences) and edges (representing the distances..where the length of the edge increases as the score increases), and also color-code the nodes by whether they are from "LV" or "CD4". Is there a way to do this in R?

My coding skills are subpar at best so I would be really grateful for any help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding the sample data along with your question to reproduce it. You can get the sample data using `dput(df)` (where df is the name of your data frame) from your RConsole.

Comment: thanks! I will consider that from now on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, from my previous experience doing Bioinformatics decades ago, there are already good graphical representations to show similarity between DNA sequences. One option I recall uses sequence dot plots, and R has at least 2 packages for doing that: `seqinr` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqinr/index.html) and `dotplot` (https://github.com/evolvedmicrobe/dotplot). One option that is not an R package but a web tool, is YASS (https://bioinfo.cristal.univ-lille.fr/yass/index.php).

For some alternative metrics and representations, see: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9097943 ("Levenshtein Distance, Sequence Comparison and Biological Database Search"), https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4880953/ ("Similarity Estimation Between DNA Sequences Based on Local Pattern Histograms of Binary Images"), and https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271876/1-s2.0-S0888613X07X01403/1-s2.0-S0888613X07000382/main.pdf ("Distance measures for biological sequences: Some recent approaches")

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answers. From what I understood these first tools do things a bit different from what I want..What I have are many short sequences which I want to compare together simultaneously, so I thought plotting a distance score would be best (I chose levenshtein because it considers insertions, deletions, mutations in the score..which is what I want). Plotting the similarity between only 2 sequences wouldn't help me in that case actually..